# Calculate variance across columns in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, multiple-columns, variance

How can I calculate variance across numerous columns in a pyspark ?
For e.g. if the pyspark.sql.dataframe table is:

```
ID  A   B   C
1   12  15  7
2   6   15  2
3   56  25  25
4   36  12  5
```

and output needed is

```
ID  A   B   C   Variance
1   12  15  7   10.9
2   6   15  2   29.6
3   56  25  25  213.6
4   36  12  5   176.2
```

There is a variance function in pyspark but it works only column-wise.

Answer (score 3):

Just concat the columns that you need using `concat_ws` function and use udf to calculate variance like below

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from statistics import pvariance

def calculateVar(row):
    data = [float(x.strip()) for x in row.split(",")]
    return pvariance(data)

varUDF = udf(calculateVar,FloatType())
df.withColumn('Variance',varUDF(concat_ws(",",df.a,df.b,df.c))).show()
```

output :

```
+---+---+---+---+---------+
| id|  a|  b|  c| Variance|
+---+---+---+---+---------+
|  1| 12| 15|  7|10.888889|
|  2|  6| 15|  2|29.555555|
|  3| 56| 25| 25|213.55556|
|  4| 36| 12|  5|176.22223|
+---+---+---+---+---------+
```