# Pyspark variance across columns using Pandas udf

Tags: pandas, pyspark, user-defined-functions

New to pyspark and struggling with simple things.I want to define a Pandas UDF that take multiple columns as input and calculate the variance on rows for those input columns.

But I get errors.

I tried to specify input as a list. But that didn't work. How could this be solved?

This didn't work for me either.
[Calculate variance across columns in pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43683792/calculate-variance-across-columns-in-pyspark)

```
test = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'],
'feat1': [3,4,5,6, 7],
'feat2': [6, 9, 2, 4, 5]
})

test['var_pd'] = test[['feat1', 'feat2']].var(axis = 1)

test = spark.createDataFrame(test)
from typing import List
@pandas_udf(returnType=DoubleType())
def variance_udf(*cols:List[pd.Series]) -> pd.Series:
    return pd.Series(cols).var(axis=1)

test = test.withColumn("variance_udf", variance_udf('feat1', 'feat2'))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = spark.createDataFrame(
    [('a', 3, 6), ('b', 4, 9)],
    schema=['id', 'feat1', 'feat2']
)

df.printSchema()
df.show(5, False)
root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- feat1: long (nullable = true)
 |-- feat2: long (nullable = true)

+---+-----+-----+
|id |feat1|feat2|
+---+-----+-----+
|a  |3    |6    |
|b  |4    |9    |
+---+-----+-----+
```

You can pass all the columns into the UDF by using non keyword arguments:

```
@func.udf(returnType=FloatType())
def variance_udf(*cols):
    return float(variance([int(x) for x in cols]))

df.withColumn(
    'variance_udf',
    variance_udf(*[df[col] for col in df.columns[1:]])
).show(
    10, False
)
+---+-----+-----+------------+
|id |feat1|feat2|variance_udf|
+---+-----+-----+------------+
|a  |3    |6    |4.5         |
|b  |4    |9    |12.5        |
+---+-----+-----+------------+
```

Or you can use the RDD operations:

```
from statistics import variance    
df.rdd.map(lambda row: (row[0], float(variance([int(x) for x in row[1:]])))).toDF(['id', 'var']).show(5, False)
+---+----+
|id |var |
+---+----+
|a  |4.5 |
|b  |12.5|
+---+----+
```

Comment: I need to import func from somewhere? @func.udf(returnType=FloatType())

Comment: @Henri It's a spark sql functions module importing `from pyspark.sql import functions as func`

Comment: ah, sorry. I was confused, already had from pyspark.sql import functions as F Thx!