# How to send the whole row of a pyspark dataframe to a UDF function so that the function can access the values by the column names?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, databricks

How to send the whole row of a pyspark dataframe to a UDF function so that the function can access the values by the column names? For example, let's say we have a dataframe -

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([(2, 25, 4, 10), (6, 30, 9, 11), (8, 35, 12, 18)], ["A", "B", "C", "D"])
```

And we have this function -

```
def func(row):
  return row.A + row.B

udf_func = udf(func)
```

I want to create another column (let's say new_column) which stores the sum of column "A" and "B" but I want to send the whole row to the function and let the function choose the columns to return the sum.

I tried this line of code -

```
df = df.withColumn("new_column", udf_my_function(struct([col(x) for x in df.columns])))
```

But this is creating a new_column containing only null values.

Can anyone please help me with this? I am new to pyspark and databricks.

Thanks!

**Edit: ** Normally with pandas we do this thing easily. Let's say we define a function -

```
def func(row):
    return row.A + row.B
```

I want to do this in pyspark -

```
df["new_col"] = df.apply(func, axis=1)
```

Comment: What is your expected output dataframe look like? I still don't understand the "whole row" thing

Comment: Does this help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76089926/10445333?

Comment: @HoangMinhQuangFX15045 The expected output dataframe contains a new column (along with the existing columns A, B, C, D) with sum of columns A and B.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/40278664/1477418

Comment: Trying the `struct` solution you tried seems to be producing the correct values. How did you see these  nulls?

Comment: @IslamElbanna Yes, it is working now. At that time, I don't know why it was not working.

Answer (score 0):

It seems what @DonkeyKong tried is working fine, just adding the answer here in case it can be useful for anyone else.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, udf, struct

def func(row):
  return row.A + row.B

udf_func = udf(func)

df = spark.createDataFrame([(2, 25, 4, 10), (6, 30, 9, 11), (8, 35, 12, 18)], ["A", "B", "C", "D"])

df = df.withColumn("new_column", udf_func(struct([col(x) for x in df.columns])))

df.show()
```

```
+---+---+---+---+----------+                                                    
|  A|  B|  C|  D|new_column|
+---+---+---+---+----------+
|  2| 25|  4| 10|        27|
|  6| 30|  9| 11|        36|
|  8| 35| 12| 18|        43|
+---+---+---+---+----------+
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do something like row[["A","B"]] inside the function?

Comment: Sorry what do you mean by row[["A", "B"]] ? to return an array of these two columns?

Comment: Just like we do it in pandas to select specific columns. In the func function if I want to something like row[["A", "B"]] i.e., select only the columns A and B, how do I do it in pyspark.

Comment: Ahh, then you can do `df.select("A", "B")`

Comment: This is not working. Normally this works on a spark dataframe but mind that I want to do this inside the function. In the answer that you wrote just add this code row = row.select("A", "B") before the return statement and run it. I am getting an attribute error here.

Comment: ah if you need to access the `Row` then you can convert it into a python `dict` using `row.asDict()` and then if you need to select values of some keys you can do something like `[row.asDict().get(key) for key in ['A', 'B']]` which will produce `[2, 25]` for the first row